# Set priority on laravel eloquent query(with mongodb)

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package on my project.

I am trying to perform a whereIn query that first will get all the results from an array of ids and then complete the rest of the results from another condition.

Something like this:

```
$ids = [88,206,333,4786,5001];

$query = List::where(function($q){
   $q->whereIn('id',$ids')->orWhere('shouldDisplay',true);
})
->where('new',true)
->take(10)
->get();
```

This query should first look for the values in the ids array and then look for other record matching the second orWhere query.

Desired results :

```
Collection {
   0 => id number 88 results set ,
   1 => id number 206 results set ,
   2 => id number 333 results set ,
   3 => id number 4786 results set ,
   4 => id number 5001 results set ,
   5 => id number "something from database" results set ,
   6 => id number "something from database" results set ,
   7 => id number "something from database" results set ,
   8 => id number "something from database" results set ,
   9 => id number "something from database" results set
}
```

I know its can be done by two queries.. but i want to fetch this data only by one query.

is it even possible?

Comment: Can you provide an example of documents you wish to query?